# All Windows 7 host are pinging to 127.0.0.1.home when host name is used

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ping

I have a local area network of four Windows 7 PCs. The PCs are named Term1, Term2, Term3 and Term4.

**Term1 is the server PC.**

When I map to Term1 from the other Terms(2,3 and 4) I always used the command:

```
Net use F: \\Term1\c /user:Admin 1234
```

This worked fine before; now it suddenly refuses to connect this way – I have to replace Term1 with the actual IP address of Term1 for it to work.

***I have tried the following Admin CMD commands:***

1. `netsh int ip reset`
2. `ipconfig /flushdns`

All of these commands make no difference; I just can't connect using the server name (Term1).

What I strangely noticed is that from any of the terminals connected to Term1 (using the IP address); if I use, for example, `ping Term1`, I get an address return of **`127.0.0.1.home`**; this address of **`127.0.0.1.home`** will display if I ping to Term2, Term3 or Term4.

I cannot find any solution on the web for this strange problem.

Comment: What exactly does ping print? 127.0.0.1.home is not an address, it is a name. What's more insteresting is that .home is (or will soon be) a valid top level domain, that has been delayed because of fears of name collisions, since .home has been widely used on internal networks.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday we experienced the same issue at several of our customers.

The only workaround that we have found thus far is to edit the hosts file on each workstation to point to the correct server IP-address.

for example:

10.0.0.250    server

10.0.0.251    Term1

We have found the problem occuring on PCs of different types and quality (i.e. white box PCs, Dell), running OS's ranging from Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. Some of the PCs update regularly, some have not updated in weeks or months. So at this point in time it does not appear to be a specific Windows update that causes this.

So far the only common denominator is that all the affected customers are using Dlink ADSL routers that act as the DHCP-server on the network.

Comment: Since my server was generating a dynamic ip each time a re-boot is done pointing to a server ip address would not help. The only solution is to set a static ip address on the server and then link the terminals to that static ip address !

I still wonder why the host names are not resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just linking from one PC to another then the names won't be registered via your DNS server which would be public and not have local pc names registered.

With the above, the only way to get the host names resolved would be to edit the hosts file and add a name and ip address for each computer. The file is located here:

C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

If you are using Active Directory then your domain controller will function as the DNS server and will register the names and ip addresses once they are joined to the domain which will make connecting by name possible.

As you've already done, it's best to have static ip addresses for servers.

Comment: Windows computers typically implement LLMNR (Link Local Multicast Name Resolution), with which local hosts tell each other their names without involving DNS. But that's beside the point, the problem here is that there is something fishy going on: ping responds with **host name** `127.0.0.1.name`. Afaik, static IP addresses are in use. We will have to wait for more details.

Comment: I've had cases where Windows computers were on the same subnet and could only be reached via ip address and not by hostname. In his case, there is something else happening as he could normally connect by hostname but can't anymore.